# Official self-references in the World of Darkness setting?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, world-of-darkness, metagaming

**Are there official self-references in either World of Darkness setting** (that is, "in-game")**?** Does White Wolf exist within their own universe? Are people playing *Vampire: The Masquerade* (or *The Requiem*) or any other WW game *in* the (o/n)WoD?

Obviously, as a Storyteller, anyone can bring such a self-reference and/or metareference into the game ("So you met this Storyteller at a Con who turned out to be a real Ravnos!", "I'm going to play a Guardian of the Veil who's always been an rpg geek and is now patrolling the net looking for breaches of secrecy on sites like RPG.SE and such") -- but **I'm not looking for unofficial instances. Please, cite official mentions only,** be they from rulebooks, comics, novels, computer games... whatever published officially **by White Wolf.** :)

(For bonus points, mention famous WoD "inspirers" as well, such as *Anne Rice*, for example. Again, official sources only.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The analog to White Wolf and the World of Darkness game lines in the classic World of Darkness setting is the **Black Dog Game Factory**. They were detailed fully in *[Subsidiaries: A Guide To Pentex](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1565043588)*, although there are earlier references in other books. The staffers described therein are parodies of the employees of White Wolf, and the entire sourcebook entry is a pastiche of the adventure games hobby circa the time it was published. (An updated version was included in the W20 version of *Book of the Wyrm*, and was [published on the Onyx Path website](http://theonyxpath.com/day-4-poking-fun-a-look-at-book-of-the-wyrm/).)

The games published by BDGF for their "romantic-rage" setting, the World of Shadow, are:

- Revenant: The Ravishing (Earlier references have *Zombie: The Putrescence* instead.)
- Lycanthrope: The Rapture
- Warlock: The Pretension
- Spectre: The Annihilation
- Pixie: The Delusion
- Human: The Protagonist
- Fiend: The Pacting

As a further "meta" reference, White Wolf used the name "Black Dog" as a publishing imprint for works that could be considered more extreme or controversial than otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, this is an excellent answer. It's weird I've missed this, especially since HoL, one of Black Dog's real world games is one of my favorite funny rpgs. :)

Comment: They also take a shot at some other games companies too, guess who makes the game 'Spreadsheets in Space'!

Comment: @ClaraOnager I actually think that's a self-dig; "Spreadsheets in Space" is a nickname for EVE Online, which is run by CCP, who owned White Wolf at the time.