# What is World Of Shadows?

Tags: world-of-darkness

I have recently become aware of a world similar to world of darkness called world of shadows but all the wiki tells me regarding that world is that it is a parody of world of darkness. I scoured the internet for places where the books that describe world of shadows but i had no luck. In any case my question is that is world of shadows just a parody with no actual books or is it a setting with it's book removed from sale?

Comment: Got a source for the parody of WoD interpretation? I can find plenty of things called "World of Shadows," but no trace of that idea.

Comment: @JohnDallman I've linked to another rpg.stackexchange question that addresses it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "World of Shadow" is the game line [produced by Black Dog Game Factory](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/17023/official-self-references-in-the-world-of-darkness-setting/17024#17024), the parody game company run by Pentex in *Werewolf: the Apocalypse*. It's detailed in **Book of the Wyrm** and **Subsidiaries**. There are no real books affiliated with it; it's an in-game entity.