# Which of the 21 fictional companies listed as owned by Pentex in Book of the Wyrm are references to real companies?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse

The Werewolf supplement *Book of the Wyrm* describes the Pentex Corporation and other Wyrm-tainted stuff. Pages 37-39 (in the first edition) list 21 fictional corporations owned by Pentex.

A couple of these were instantly recognizable to me as parodies or references to real-world business. For example, "Endron International",  a petrochemical company infamous for large oil spills, is a parody of the Enron Corporation (which has a branch called Enron International). Enron was a global energy company with diverse business interests which was accused of ignoring pipeline leaks.

Which of these 21 corporations are parodies or references to real-world businesses?

Comment: Asked in the spirit of these kinds of [Who Are ...](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100278/who-are-these-dc-superheroes) questions. I'm also a bit unclear how much text from the original book I can lawfully post here.

Comment: As much as is germane to the Q&A, I would think.  You don't need any more than you have, in the question, but an answer would obviously need to at least mention the fictional names of each company with a reference and probably those without references as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Endron International

A reference to [the Enron Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enron). Both are primary energy companies (Endron is an oil company, Enron was focused on electricity and natural gas) that have become conglomerates with diverse business interests. Enron also had a division called Enron International.

### Avalon, Inc.

Similar to [Avalon Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalon_Hill), a publisher of wargames and strategy board games. Like Avalon Inc their games are focused on war and violence.

### King Breweries and Distillers

A reference to [Anheuser-Busch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anheuser-Busch). They produce Budweiser which is marketed as the "king of beers". Like King Breweries, they have been accused of marketing their products to teenagers.

### Herculean Firearms Inc.

Refers to [Olympic Arms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_Arms), who was party to a number of lawsuits regarding the constitutionality of firearms regulations. They are also the manufacturer of the AR-15 and M16, which matches the description of Herculean Firearms as a manufacturer of automatic and semi-automatic weapons.

### O'Tolley’s

An international fast-food franchise, O'Tolley’s is a pastiche of [McDonald's](https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us.html). The Scottish "Mac" is replaced by the Irish "O'," the similarity between "Donald" and "Tolley" in sound, and the description of the chain as "the family place" matches McDonald's corporate branding in the late 80s-early 90s.

### Sunburst Enterprises International

A reference to [Sun Microsystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Microsystems), a company that produced server hardware and technologies.

### Young & Smith

This manufacturer of household pharmaceuticals is a parody of [Procter & Gamble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procter_%26_Gamble). It's also two prominent figures in Mormon history.

### Black Dog Game Factory

A reference to [White Wolf Publishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Wolf_Publishing). Many of White Wolf's games are about supernatural creatures and their conflicts with each other and mortals. Black Dog's games are about "tragically hip antiheroes who kill and maim the uncool mortals in their paths, all the while moaning about their tortured souls." For more on BDGF, you can [read this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/17023/official-self-references-in-the-world-of-darkness-setting/17024#17024).

Black Dog *also* was [White Wolf's imprint label](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Wolf_Publishing#Imprints_and_labels) for "supplements with mature and adult themes" ([here](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Dog)).

### ... and several are pastiches

In addition to the companies that above that appear to be parody, there are several entries that seem to be pastiches of entire industries. Although the names may reference real companies, the details are drawn from different companies in the same industry.

- **Hallahan Fishing Company** is reminiscent of [H&N Fishing Company](https://www.hnfoods.com/get-to-know#ourstory), one of the largest seafood companies in north america. Hallahan is noted for illegal whaling and covert ops, but I could not find any mention online of real-life H&N engaging in these activities. There are allegations of various fishing companies being engaged in whaling (or harming endangered sealife). Some real-life company seems to have [hired private security](https://www.motherjones.com/environment/2008/04/exclusive-cops-and-former-secret-service-agents-ran-black-ops-green-groups/) and investigation firms to dig in to environmental groups.

Comment: What makes O'Tolley's a pastiche of McDonald's and not any other fast-food-franchise?

Comment: @findusl The Scottish "Mac" replaced by the Irish "O'," the similarity between "Donald" and "Tolley" in sound, and the description of the chain as "the family place," which matches McDonald's corporate branding in the late 80s-early 90s.

Comment: Do you have a source that Endron is based on of the energy company Enron (famous for its financial mismanagement) rather than the oil company Exxon (famous for its oil spills)?